# Many to many relationship check

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have two models, User and Client, which should be many-to-many relationship. I'm new to  lumen/laravel, so I was wondering what would be right way to check if the User belongs to Client ? Let's say I have a $client,  and the user $user model, what kind of eloquent query should I write to check if the $user belongs to $client ?

Answer (score 0):

In you client mode add the `hasMany` relation,

```
public function client(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Client');
}
```

To get the client details,

```
$users = User::first();
print_r($users->client);
```

Comment: While the suggestion to use relationships is a good one, you're example creates a [**one-to-many**](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship, while the OP specifically stated that the relation should be [**many-to-many**](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). That would require the method used to be `belongsToMany`, not `hasMany`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method to your model. For example, in your User model, you can create a `hasClient` method. This method can accept a client or the client id. Then, it will loop through all of the user's clients and check if passed-in argument matches any of the user's clients.

```
// Accepts the client's id or client
public function hasClient($id)
{
    // If you pass in an instance of the client model,
    // we will extract the id from that model
    if ($id instanceof Model)
    {
        $id = $id->getKey();
    }

    // Loop through all of the user's clients and see if any match
    foreach ($this->clients as $client)
    {
        if ($client->id == $id)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now, assuming you have a user and a client:

```
$user = User::first();
$client = Client::first();
```

You can do this to check if the user has that client:

```
if ($user->hasClient($client))
{
    // User has client. Do something.
}
```